# How can I make a translucent material that looks like this axolotl tail?

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency, shader-nodes

How can I achieve a material that looks like this thin, translucent, frosted flesh, like an axolotl tail?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You could use a mix between a *Principled BSDF* (with *Subsurface Scattering*) and *Translucent + Transparent* nodes, create a b&w image as factor so that only the kind of fins are translucent:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! +1 but.. @Allen Simpson recently pointed out in a comment [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258196/35559) that _Translucent BSDF_ is designed to be added to, rather than mixed with, other shaders.. something I hadn't realized, myself.

Comment: ok, interesting, so in my case how should I plug the Translucent?

Comment: I guess physical precision isn't really the issue here, so it's no big deal, but Allen recommended an _Add Shader_ node. In that case, it certainly looks better. Not sure about this one.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, I usually add a _Translucent BSDF_ as well because the problem with mixing is, although the transulcency is used as a surface shader, it doesn't give any surface information like reflection, roughness etc. so mxing it in to a certain percentage would take away the surface information to this amount. Not professionally speaking :D Like an _Emission_ shader as well. It makes the surface emit light but doesn't provide any other surface qualities.

Answer (score 10):

My approach is very similar to mixing shaders and masks. I use 2 Principled BSDF shaders, because I wanted Subsurface and Roughness on both Layers.

[image: ShaderNodeTree]

The shader relatively works the same in both EEVEE and Cycles, although EEVEE and its Shaders require the Screen Space Reflection and Refraction settings to be enabled and perhaps tweaked.

### Cycles

[image: RenderingCycles]

### EEVEE

[image: RenderingEvee]

### Outer Layer

The `outerLayer` placed, BSDF node has 2 painted Image Textures and 2 Musgrave Textures to control Roughness and Transmission of the *fin* and the outer layer of the *body*.
Subsurface Color controls the tint of this translucent Layer.

[image: OuterLayer]

### Inner Layer

The `innerLayer` placed, BSDF node has 1 painted Image Texture, which is connected to the Bump socket. The material tint is also controlled by the Subsurface Color.

[image: InnerLayer]

### Mix Shader Factor

The Mix Shader Factor is controlled by a mix of 2 painted Image Textures and color ramps, which controls the visibility of the veins and the transition between the inner and the outer `Bodylayer`.

[image: Mix Shader Factor]

### Mask Inner Bump

[image: Mask Inner Bump]

I will post the images of the roughness and the main mask in the future, feel free to use the Blender file below:

[Packed Blender File (42,4MB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AEPWQ9iaEevBHPlqz4xX8YemjORZ_vMM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Wow, this is an incredibly smart shader mix! Very flexible and performant design and well thought out! ...but @RobinBetts surely has an even more expert comment ready. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

*The core for Transluence shader was already described.

So just to join the party :)*

---

Three meshes - veins, muscle, skin in one object ... because if I would move veins into a separate object SSS wouldn't be calculated in the muscle shader.

Three materials are just variations of Volumetric-SSS-Transluence-Alpha ...

**Veins** (faked by *Ivy* addon)
[image]
[image]

**Muscles**
[image]
[image]

**Skin** (Shrink/Fatten Alt+S from Muscle)
[image]

[image]
[image]

Mixed ...

[image]

[image]

Note: For more natural result I wanted to use Volume for Muscle for softer blending with Skin, but it was overwritten by Skin Volume :(

With a bit of tweaking [Keith Morgan's model](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sculptjanuary18-day-11-nature-marine-5afbb197024449f6b78bf82df035a6dc)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @vklidu, very interesting approach! Would you be so kind as to share the blend file with us so that this can be looked at in more detail?

Comment: @quellenform No problem, just nothing more to see ... but sure easier to play with. It  just blend-exchange still cant upload compressed blend file (shame for providers to fill their storage) ... anyway - I'm not competing, I was just amazed by almost 700 views in two months for such thing :) ... and I wanted to try something, that wasn't successful as I expected, but it worked somehow.