# How do I make a texture-covered lamp mesh emit light?

Tags: mesh, texturing, lighting, emission

I've been struggling to light a mesh lamp emit light through a texture. If I make the texture itself emission shader, it makes the whole mesh emissive. I'm using a bathroom scene from here (xps file ported to blender): https://www.deviantart.com/shuubaru/art/DOAXVV-Bathroom-Scene-744652643

And it has wall lamps with textures mimicing a light coming from the middle of the texture, not from the whole texture. What I hope to achieve is something like this (this is also an xps file ported and rendered in blender by another person so they added them emitting light after porting it): [image: example of lighting]

In the image the mesh emits light but the lamp's 'paper' texture is also lit up like the lamp is inside the the mesh/texture. Any help would be appreciated! (I'm using Blender 2.93)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an *Add Shader* to add a *Translucent BSDF* which allows light to travel through a mesh to the camera.  Masking the effect may still be desirable, but this should give you good realism from the start.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258196/110840

Here is an answer with a good illustration.

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieved this, was using a "mask" for the emission of the material.
I will attach a picture, so you see what I mean by that.

[image]